# question about React useState Infinite Re-renders

Tags: reactjs

Is it correct that if a state is set to the same value as its initial value (like here we do setCount(1)), React will not trigger a re-render?
Regardless of the incorrect usage of the setCount in the render logic in the provided code snippet, I'm curious why it leads to infinite re-renders. This inquiry is solely for learning purposes.

```
function App(props) {
  const [count,setCount]=useState(1)

 setCount(1)
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes it wil cause infinite re-renders. Did you try it? Not sure what your question is... You should never call a `set****` like so

Answer (score 0):

It will re render infinitely ! See this stackblitz for confirmation : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-psegx9?file=src%2FApp.tsx

The setX function always trigger a re-render (see https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate). Thus you will have infinite rerenders since you call setCount on render.

To avoid this and depending on your use case, you could use something like useMemo.

Comment: thank you for your response , i already know it will cause infinit re-render - i asked ,if a state is set to the same value as its initial value  (like here we do setCount(1)), React will not trigger a re-render , so (Regardless *) of the incorrect usage of the setCount in the render logic in the provided code snippet, I'm curious why it leads to infinite re-renders.

Comment: As said in the 2nd link, setXXX ALWAYS re-renders. I guess it is linked to the implementation of useState

Answer (score 0):

A react component has a certain lifecycle.
[image]

The lifecycle has certain phases, one of them being `render`:

Now what is happening in the above code is that render phase is not being completed. It is being interrupted by `setState` which triggers another call, and queues a state update.

React has a bailing behaviour, which helps it bails out of state updates based on certain conditions. **This does not happen everytime though.**

Quote from docs:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.) Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.

Now the problem here is that a tree is not generated, and React has nothing to compare the previous and the current DOM structure.

Look at the below code:

```
function Test() {
  console.log({ child: true });
  return null;
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  console.log({ count });
  setCount(1);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`{child:true}` is never logged. Which means that even before the render phase is completed (and the tree build) the next render is triggered.

[Link to above sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rough-monad-forked-f8k5sl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C15)

When we put the above code inside a `useEffect`, React is able to diff between the two trees created.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  console.log({ count });
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(1);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, even if we are essentially doing the same thing as earlier but because we are letting the tree being created, React is able to bail out of state update.

[Link to above sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rough-monad-forked-7wz2g4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A4%2C1-16%2C2)

Comment: thanks a lot! Your patient explanation helped clear up my confusion. so to recap if i say right ,essentially, the issue arises because the render phase of the component is being interrupted by the setState, and as a result, the tree structure isn't completed. Without a completed tree structure, React has nothing to compare between the previous and current Virtual DOM structures during the state update. This is why, when we use useEffect to allow the completion of the tree creation, React can then properly bail out of the state update by comparing the previous and current trees.

Comment: Yes. To be honest, I could not find a doc for all of it, but by running that demo this is what can be inferred

Comment: Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helps correctly answer your question. If something is missing, please let me know what

Comment: i already did it many times but it says (Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.)